# Can I force apt-get install to skip upgrading ca-certificates as the upgrade is failing on Debian GNU/Linux 9?

Tags: debian, apt, kubernetes

I am trying to install a package using apt-get on Debian. However, for some reason, it also wants to upgrade ca-certificates. Can I force apt-get install to skip upgrading ca-certificates as the upgrade is failing due to a read-only file system? I am looking for a workaround as I don't to mess up with the certificates of the host (it's a kubernetes api-server host).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The upgrade is failing because the file system is read-only, which means you won’t be able to install `procps` either.

The general answer to prevent upgrades is to put a hold on the package:

```
apt-mark hold ca-certificates
```

but in your case you might need to rebuild the container image instead.